# using "graphviz" package in "phabricator" wiki

Tags: graphviz, phabricator

How can one install and use graphviz in phabricator? 
I would like to write code directly in the wiki and have the image be generated on the fly.

There seems to be a ticket open on this:
https://secure.phabricator.com/D7332
https://secure.phabricator.com/T3964

but I couldn't find any documentation beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
dot {{{
   digraph foo {
      ...
   }
}}}
```

Comment: I get `No interpreter found: dot`. Presumably there's some procedure to install this?

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer do this, as the [`dot` interpreter has been removed](https://secure.phabricator.com/T9408). (Interpreters such as `dot` that allow users to pass arbitrary code to external programs are generally not very secure, and someone had actually [developed an attack](https://hackerone.com/reports/88395) that could take advantage of this with `dot`.)